# Пример открытия сокета

Tags: сокеты, c++

Добрый день, можете мне привести в качестве примера листинг кода c++, чтобы открывался сокет к сайту "example.com" по порту 716, допустим. А то вообще не могу разобраться.

P.S. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Просто ради интереса набрал в гугле

      c++ socket client example

и во второй строке вывода ссылка на пример кода.

(копировать ее сюда просто лень).

@Семен Савенко, если Вы этого не делали, то почему?

Или Вы ждали какого-то "особого" кода?

Comment: @avp, тебе тоже спасибо, я не знал просто даже какой запрос наиболее релевантен, поэтому и спросил тут, я просто в таких штуках, как Python,PHP,Perl спокойно делаю сокеты, там это вроде ООП, на плюсах первый раз делаю, не мог найти

Comment: @alexlz, не релевантные ответы сервера были по моим запросам

Comment: @Семен Саенко, ну если результат Вас теперь устраивает, то поздравляю. Кстати, в Вашем вопросе не было указано, что речь идёт о виндах. В posix-системах пример был бы другим.

И ещё, мне непонятны все эти "делаю сокеты", "открыть порт" и пр. В таких случаях я часто стараюсь уточнить, о чём идёт речь. Если бы где-нибудь был словарь таких выражений...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// получить данные о сервере
    ulAddress = inet_addr(adrs);
        if (ulAddress == INADDR_NONE){
            ptrHost = gethostbyname(adrs);

          if (!ptrHost)
            {
                err=WSAGetLastError();

                return err;
            }
            memcpy(&sin.sin_addr, ptrHost->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(IN_ADDR));
        } else {
            memcpy(&sin.sin_addr, &ulAddress, 4);
        }
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_port   = htons(port);
// установить соединение с сервером
       if ( connect(s, (PSOCKADDR)&sin, sizeof(SOCKADDR)))
        {
         err=WSAGetLastError();
         return err;
        }
```

adrs это LPCTSTR строка "example.com", port это int port=716; Кроме того надо предварительно:

```
rc = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &WSAData);
... 
// открыть сокет
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET){...
```

(просто у меня все в разных функция, не стал все копировать-вставлять)
После коннекта можно отправлять-получать данные

Comment: красавчик, спасибо